# TabBarController + TableViewController + Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tableview

I'm new to iphone development, and I want to make an app combining TabBarController + `UITableViewController` + `UINavigationController`. I know this question was widely discussed in some video tutorials and threads, but some of them are for old xcode and sdk versions, and I have problems when working through the tutorials.

I will be glad if someone could help me with an up to date tutorial or source files.

To be clear, I'm trying to have my app based on a tab bar controller with two tabs: the second will be a simple view, and the first should contain a tableviewcontroller and a navigation controller. When I click on a cell, it should move to another "detail" view.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is going be long:

in the `AppDelegate.h`
allocate a `UITabBarController` a `UINavigationController` and 2 `UIViewControllers`

for example:

```
UITabBarController *mainTabBar;
UINavigationController *navController;
UIViewController *firstViewController;
UIViewController *secondViewController;
```

then move to `AppDelegate.m` and instantiate each of those 4 items like this:

```
mainTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

firstViewController = [[firstView alloc] init];
```

do that for both views

then if you want to set the title of either of the views, (this will be the title that shows up in the tab bar) do it as follows:

```
firstViewController.title = @"Welcome";
```

Then create the `UINavigationController` for the view that has a `UITableView` inside it like this:

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navController  pushViewController:firstViewController animated:NO];
```

Now you have a `UIViewController` and a `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` inside it.

All thats left is to put your two tabs into the `UITabBarController`:

```
mainTabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController,  nil];
```

then just put the tab bar controller on screen and you should be good to go:

```
[window addSubview:mainTabBar.view];
```

A couple things to remember:

- make sure you release everything you called alloc on so your using good memory management.
- Make sure you import all the files you intend on using in `AppDelegate.h`, it should look something like: `#import "FirstView.h`

Let me know in a comment if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks for taking all this time to answer user635633. I make a new project through your solution, and it's good yes. Just one bug at first because the viewcontroller doesn't appear, so i modified this line as below :

'mainTabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, secondViewController,  nil]; '

so just now I'll add the tableview into the ViewController as I understand. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting problems with adding a view, containing TableViewController to the stack when I click on some button on the FirstViewController. Any idea ?

Comment: your right about that correction.  Sorry, I just mixed up what should have been in the Tab Bar.  I'm glad this helped.

Comment: have a button in the view.  Link in in Interface builder to an IBAction, then in that method allocate a new viewController: `tableViewController = [[tableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:nil];` then just push the new view controller: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

The document on Apple's developer's library portal, titled [Combined View Controller Interfaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html), explains how what you are after can be done both through the use of Interface Builder as well as programmatically. I recently followed the documentation on that page to create a part of an application that did entirely what you want to do.

Comment: Ok Ayaz thank you. I'll concentrate on that doc and hope i'll get satisfied inchallah.